# decrease translate-x value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm building a carousel and whenever the user clicks on the next button the transform value needs to update by -20%.

On first click the carousel moves by -20% which is great however, after each click there on, the value decreases by less than 20% - the value is 16% and continues to decrease under 20 - unsure why? I need the value to decrease only by 20% each click.

Here is my UPDATED SOLUTION CODE:

```
const handleCarouselNext = function* (payload) {
  const currentIndex = payload.currentIndex;
  const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('CYHH-carousel-carousel')[0];
  slides.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + (100 - constants.slideAnimation) + '%)';
  constants.slideAnimation = constants.slideAnimation - 20;
  yield put({ type: actions.CAROUSEL_NEXT_DONE, payload: inc(currentIndex) });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

16% = 20% *0.8

In other words you are applying the "times 0.8" after each click instead of only one time (as you want to keep it at constant 20%.)

So just removing this should do the trick: constants.slideAnimation = constants.slideAnimation * 80/100;

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work on the second click - first click does.

Comment: So what happens on the second click?

Comment: I missunderstood the OP then. How exactly do you want to value to behave?

Comment: On each click to update the value by -20%. So the second click the value should be -40%, the third -60% etc...

Comment: How about:

constants.slideAnimation = constants.slideAnimation*(100-20 * ONE_PER);

Comment: Unfortunately not - I wonder if it's because we are changing the value of a constant?

Comment: Aah yeah you are right. I think my comment would work if you could calculate the value for each step separately (aka just replace the ONE_PER with step number).

I am not sure how to achieve the same with a recursive method like you are using.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
With this line :

first time is ok - 20% but secund way it is 20% from 80% ....
 constants.slideAnimation = constants.slideAnimation * 80/100;

```
// execute just one time on load or some init func 
 var ONE_PER =  constants.slideAnimation / 100;
```

this line no need to be were :

```
const slides = document.getElementsByClassName('CYHH-carousel-carousel')[0];
```

also no need to be const . Move this line out of click event and make it like this :

```
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('CYHH-carousel-carousel')[0];

  //try and check values with console.log 
  console.log(" value for 1 per :" + ONE_PER)
  console.log(" value for constants.slideAnimation :" + constants.slideAnimation)
  constants.slideAnimation = constants.slideAnimation - (20 * ONE_PER);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same result with this solution.

Comment: what this class means ('CYHH-carousel-carousel') . Is it current slider frame(item) ?

Comment: It is the UL that contain the slides are within LI's etc

Comment: ONE_PER is ti const value ?

Comment: const value = 80. I just tried your code and it's incrementing like this within the console logs: 80, 64, 48, 32, 16. Needs to be 80, 60, 40, 20, 0 etc

Comment: is it because we are changing the value of a constant? constants.slideAnimation has the value of 80 then we are updating again??

Comment: This bug is so simple , something else make problem here . Please give as online code snippet with your example , than you will get answer fast answer  i am sure 100% .